# PHP inside ce-img

Tags: ce-image

Why can’t I place this in ce-img?  is there a way around that or plugin that can do that?

‘$kentekenM’ comes from another database

```
{exp:ce_img:single 
        src="/images/uploads/kentekenplaat.gif" 
        text=" <?php echo "$kentekenM";?>|0,0|36|36|#000|system/expressionengine/third_party/ce_img/fonts/kenteken.ttf|left||left,top|52,18|100||||" 
        alt="kenteken {last_segment}” title=”{last_segment}” }
```

Answer (score 0):

For php tags to work within a template you need to turn on php processing via a system setting.  Your tag should work once you have done this.

Enabling php processing in a template is not always a good idea (it is turned off by default for a reason).  Depending what else your template is doing there might be more appropriate ways of pulling in the value from the other database.

More information on this [in the EE documentation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/php.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead of **Enabling PHP** within a template, you should go for creating a small plugin (which have `pi.plugin_name.php` file inside `plugin_name` folder).

It is advice-able to create `pi` file because you can fire database query from this file. While you can also give more than one database connection in `database.php` (for `EE2`) and `config.php` (for `EE3`).

You just need to connect another database and fetch appropriate data from the `pi` file. And you can easily populate data into front-end by `{exp:plugin_name}`.